# Do you say "food wasn't good" or "food wasn't nice"?

Tags: word-choice

Do you say "the food wasn't good" or "the food wasn't nice"?

Could you explain the difference between the two?

When I said "the food wasn't nice" during my online lesson, the teacher corrected it to "good".

Comment: Neither is particularly common compared to [*the food **was no good.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+food+was+no+good%2C+the+food+wasn%27t+good%2Cthe+food+wasn%27t+nice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20food%20was%20no%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20food%20was%20not%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20food%20was%20not%20nice%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20food%20was%20no%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20food%20was%20not%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20food%20was%20not%20nice%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I suggest you ask your teacher.  For me both "good" and "nice" are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, at school, I had written: 'What I did on Saturday: I saw a nice film, then had a nice meal, and I saw my aunt who has a nice dog', my teacher would probably have handed it back and have asked for three different adjectives. The main objection to 'nice' is that it is vague and imprecise. When I was young, its use was discouraged by my teachers for this reason. It gives little information beyond denoting acceptableness. Why say someone or something is nice when you can be more specific? A man isn’t just nice, he’s polite in social settings, or kind, or helpful. The water in the lake isn’t just nice, it’s crystal clear and just the right temperature. A dress isn't just nice, it's well-made, or stylish, or has an attractive pattern or colour.

Of course, 'nice' has its uses in conversation, where nuances of meaning can be provided by various means, and economy of expression is valued.

> 1. It’s a nothing word.
>
> “Nice” is a nothing, non-committal word that brings neither color,
> flair, nor definite meaning to your writing. If you’re contemplating
> using the word “nice” I’d seriously recommend buying a Thesaurus and
> seeing what other words you can muster.

Four more reasons here:

[Why you should ban the word 'nice' from your writing](https://medium.com/@katie.ginger/why-you-should-ban-the-word-nice-from-your-writing-7038aee07b66)

Having said all that, I don't think the teacher's substitute is very much better, for mostly the same reasons, except that 'good' is more formal.

Answer (score 0):

They are both acceptable. People might talk of "good food" more than they do of "nice food", but it is OK to say that food was "nice", or "not nice".

If there's a difference, "good" carries the added connotation that the food was of good quality.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you are speaking American, British or Australian English. In the US for sure "good" is used, with "nice" mostly reserved for kind people and pretty objects. I know my relatives from Australia would use "nice" for tasty food, but I'm not sure about the UK.

Comment: OK for Brits too.

Answer (score -2):

"Nice" implies a personal aspect. People are nice. Inanimate objects are good.

The definition and examples are from *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/nice)*

> 1.1 (of a person) good-natured; kind.
>
> - ‘he's a really nice guy’
> - ‘There's a saying that if someone is nice to you and mean to the waiter, then he's not really a very nice person.’
> - ‘I got it from a friend of mine; she was really nice to make it for me.’

Comment: This depends on where you are: I know that my relatives from Australia use "nice" to say that food is tasty or similar things

Comment: Last night I dined at a restaurant. My steak was very nice, the fries were OK, the peas were like bullets.

Comment: The British are famous for their liking for 'a nice cup of tea'.

Comment: Kicking a cat is not a nice thing to do, but helping an old lady across the road is (if she wants to go, that is).